# Issue with importing xgboost on python jupyter notebook after installing xgboost

Tags: python, xgboost

I have successfully installed xgboost on my mac using jupyer notebook

by typing !`pip install xgboost`

However, when I `import xgboost`, the message below is what I see..

**Error:**

> OSError: dlopen(/Users/KeonPark/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/5/libgomp.1.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Users/KeonPark/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so
>     Reason: image not found

Please help.....